# Django and UDP server

Tags: django, udp, hole-punching

I have a web server built with Django. I need to update some information in the **same** database used by Django specifically through a UDP connection.

What is the best approach to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) to build a server to listen to UDP

Secondly: If you have unique constraints you **WILL** run into database deadlock issues if there are multiple UDP clients so want to use some form of serialization for your DB writes - assuming your database transactions are somewhat atomic. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) will probably do that for you, but remember to run the worker with `--concurrency=1`. Especially if your `Django` views do more than one `.save()` on a model instance.

Answer (score 0):

Build a separate socket server.
In order to use the project's database and settings do:
export PYTHONPATH='path/to/your/project' <-- it gives the ability to import from other project modules
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='projectname.settings'  <-- use project database and settings